# byte*** array to object

Tags: c++-cli

У меня имеется 3 мерный динамический массив ImgAR типа `byte***`, в нем хранятся данные картинки разбитые по координатам пикселя и цветовым каналам.
И есть метод `Write` который принимает `System::Object^`, как перевести?

Comment: Как правило, двухмерные или трехмерные структуры могут хранить данные в разных участках памяти. Нужно делать Write  каждому участку отдельно.

Comment: В C++ нет никаких `System::Object^`, используйте правильные теги для вопроса.

Comment: @ixSci `typedef System::Action<System::String^, System::Object^>^ ActionWrite` забыл указать

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, в C++ нет «шапок» `^`. Ваш вопрос имеет неправильные теги.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось проще чем я думал: `cli::array<System::Byte^, 3>^ Ar = gcnew cli::array<System::Byte^, 3>(400, 800, 3);`